# MFP 7.0 HTTP Adapter returning extra data

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I am trying to reuse an existing MFP 7.0 HTTP Adapter to get info from an external service via Jquery Ajax call...is there a way to 
not have the adapter return the /*-secure- */ part of the json data? The api is set to be unprotected. This extra data forces the ajax call
to fail with the following error:

Houston, we have a problem!: parsererror SyntaxError: Unexpected token / in JSON at position 0 {"readyState":4,"responseText":"/*-secure-\n{\"firstName\":\"...\",\"isSuccessful\":true,\"lastName\":\"...\"}*/","status":200,"statusText":"OK"}

/*-secure-{"firstName":"....","isSuccessful":true,"lastName":"..."}*/

Answer (score 0):

When you're making an AJAX call you're using AJAX, you're not using your adapter. You either use AJAX or you use the adapter, to reach your endpoint. You can't use AJAX to call an adapter to get to an endpoint, what's the point in that? The idea is to use adapters to get into backends via MobileFirst and security framework it provides you with.

If for this instance you do not require this, simply use only AJAX to get data from this external service.

As for the `/-secure- ...` text, it is there to protect from XSS attacks and cannot be removed.

Comment: Idan, You need to think before you write....it is perfectly reasonable to use an adapter that is already there and working that talks to an existing back-end service...from a NON MFP based app...or even a MFP based app for that matter. Also, The service I am calling is LDAP based and I do not want to recreate all of that code...so to use an existing adapter that is live and working makes sense to me...especially from html which this app happens to be.

Comment: Okay, let me rephrase, if you don't want the /-secure part, don't use adapters.

Comment: You can use AJAX to call an adapter that calls an endpoint. It works, just on the AJAX error path due to the /*-secure- added data....